# How to compute a column that depends on a period condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am not sure what title I should give my question, but I have clear what I want to achieve.

I have the following dataframe:

```
period = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
final_renewal_percentage = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,1]
first_renewals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
df = pd.DataFrame({'period': period, 'first_renewals': first_renewals, 'final_renewal_percentage': final_renewal_percentage})
```

I need to compute the following column `renewal_of_renewals`:

```
0    0.0 # this is 0 since period < 4
1    0.0 # this is 0 since period < 4
2    0.0 # this is 0 since period < 4
3    0.0 # this is 0 since period < 4
4    0.5 # this is 1 * 0.5 (first_renewals corresponding to period=0)
5    1.0 # this is 2 * 0.5 (first_renewals corresponding to period=1)
6    1.5 # this is 3 * 0.5 (first_renewals corresponding to period=2)
7    2.0 # this is 4 * 0.5 (first_renewals corresponding to period=3)
8    2.5 # this is 5 * 0.5 (first_renewals corresponding to period=4)
9    6.0 # this is 6 * 1 (first_renewals corresponding to period=5)
Name: renewals_of_renewals, dtype: float64
```

Basically explaining, if period is < 4, `renewals_of_renewals` is 0. Otherwise, it is the product of `first_renewals` and `final_renewal_percentage`, but the value of `first_renewals` is the corresponding value to `period - 4` (see details on dataframe)

I was able to compute this calculation by using a for loop. However, I wanna avoid using the for loop, but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just do your calculation on the whole dataframe, then afterward set the zeros where you want them like this:

```
renewals_of_renewals = np.array(df['first_renewals'])[df['period']-4] * df['final_renewal_percentage']
renewals_of_renewals[np.where(df['period'] < 4)[0]] = 0.0
```

Comment: the product of `renewals_of_renewals` is `first_renewals` and `final_renewal_percentage`

Comment: this is not working as I expect. Just from the first step I am getting a very weird output.

Comment: There, that should work.  There was some weirdness with the Dataframe indexing that I didn't account for.

Comment: it seems it works. I wonder if there is a simpler way to achieve the same. However, becuase your answer solves the problem I have, I will validate yours.

Comment: Yeah, the way that pandas was indexing made me have to convert 'first_renewals' to an `ndarray`, which makes my solution much less readable than it should be.  Perhaps a pandas expert will show up and explain a better way!

Answer (score 1):

You can build another df column based on other columns per row like this:

```
def transform_function(row):
    if row['period'] < 4:
       return float(0)
    elif row['period'] >=4:
       return row['first_renewals'] * row['final_renewal_percentage'] 


df['renewal_of_renewals'] = df.apply(lambda row: transform_function(row),axis = 1)
```

Comment: I dont understand this part very well...  `but the value of first_renewals is the corresponding value to period - 4`. But the idea is that you can do whatever you want row by row in this schema using any other columns values as you wish to produce a new column.